# How to dynamically calculate discount html/js

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, calculation

I am trying to display a percentage value from ((discount/product price) * 100) using the HTML widget of WordPress' WPForm plugin. The discount is triggered by a "Get Total" button currently but that stops the WordPress Submit button from functioning. How can I trigger the total to appear once the fields are filled in instead of using the button? Form in use here: http://testelementor.temp513.kinsta.cloud/calculator/

```
<head>
<title>HTML Calculator</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calc() {
  var p = document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_12").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_13").value;
  return (d/p)*100;
}

function GetTotal() {
   document.getElementById('answer_value').innerText = calc();
}
</script>
</head>
<form>
<input type="button" style="color:#000;" name="Get Total" value="Get Total" onclick="GetTotal()" />

<div id="answer" style="display:block;"> Percent Discount: <span id="answer_value"></span>% </div>


</form>
</body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try oninput or onchange event listener.

```js
function calc() {
  var p = document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_12").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_13").value;
  return (d/p)*100;
}

function GetTotal() {
   document.getElementById('answer_value').innerText = calc();
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>HTML Calculator</title>
</head>
<form>

<input type="number" id="wpforms-1365-field_12">
<input type="number" id="wpforms-1365-field_13" oninput="GetTotal()">

<input type="button" style="color:#000;" name="Get Total" value="Get Total" />

<div id="answer" style="display:block;"> Percent Discount: <span id="answer_value"></span>% </div>


</form>
</body>
    
</html>
```

If you can't add oninput() attribute directly to the input element, you can easily add that via JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_13").oninput = GetTotal();
```

or you can also use the onchange event listener.

```
document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_13").onchange = GetTotal();
```

The difference is:

oninput will trigger every time someone inserts a character in the input field, while onchange will only occur when the input field loses focus. So, use whichever applies to your application.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't use my own input elements/inline js. Field_12 and filed_13 are the inputs. I've tried adding the oninput() attribute/add event listener under calc() this way: var p = document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_12").value;
p.oninput = GetTotal(); and same for var d but it does fire. The rest of the code remains the same http://testelementor.temp513.kinsta.cloud/calculator/. I've also tried p.oninput = function(){alert("GetTotal");};

Is there a reason it's not working?

Comment: @EsmeJune

Do you want to only show the percentage on button click? I got the impression from your original question that you don't want it to happen at button click, rather you want the button click to submit the form. 

In that case, you don't want to use oninput inside calc() funcction. It needs to be independent. Have you tried this?: 

document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_13").oninput = GetTotal();

Answer (score 1):

Use `onchange` eventlistener for both you input fields. For convenience, I have added two input fields and removed the button and set the initial values of input as 0 so that we don't get `NaN`.

```js
function calc() {
  var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_12").value);
  var d = parseInt(document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_13").value);
  return (d/p)*100;
}

function GetTotal() {
   document.getElementById('answer_value').innerText = calc();
}
```

```html
<form>
  p - <input type="text" value="0" id="wpforms-1365-field_12" onchange="GetTotal()">
  <br>
  d - <input type="text" value="0" id="wpforms-1365-field_13" onchange="GetTotal()">
<div id="answer" style="display:block;"> Percent Discount: <span id="answer_value"></span>% </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't use my own input elements/inline js. Field_12 and filed_13 are the inputs. I've tried adding the oninput() attribute/add event listener under calc() this way: var p = document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_12").value; p.oninput = GetTotal(); and same for var d, even with onchange but it does fire. The rest of the code remains the same testelementor.temp513.kinsta.cloud/calculator. I've also tried p.oninput = function(){alert("GetTotal");}; Is there a reason it's not working?

Comment: @EsmeJune What can you modify presently? The JS or the html? If you cannot modify the html, then you can use eventlisteners in JS without altering the html.